# Create an App in Microsoft Power apps from the existing code

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I would like to create an app in MS Poer apps.
I already have a web application. I want that web application to be created in power apps.
Do I have to create the same functionality from scratch or I can re-use the my already created web application by importing the functionality and UI to power bi.

And suggestions here?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

Powerapps has his own unique language. As far as I know you can't import functionalities or UI. What you can do is, if your web application runs on top of an API, create a custom connector to the API and use the API methods in your powerapp